# Blank page after submitting external HIT in MTurk

Tags: form-submit, mechanicalturk

If I submit my external HIT with the https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit URL, it gets succesfully submitted to MTurk (in my requester Sandbox, i can see the result), but for the worker an empty / blank page appears, instead of the confirmation, that her/his HIT got submitted succesfully...

I guess, something with the action-parameter in my form could be wrong...

The **HTML-Code** of this blank page looks like:

```
<html><head>
 <title>&lt;bean:message key="external_submit.title" /&gt;</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadOuterPage() {
        var boxes = top.document.getElementsByName('autoAcceptEnabled');
        if( boxes.length == 0 || !boxes[0].checked ) {
          top.location = top.document.getElementById('hitExternalNextLink').href;
        } else {
          top.location = top.document.getElementById('hitExternalNextAcceptLink').href;
        }
    };
  </script>
 </head>
<body onload="reloadOuterPage();"><bean:message key="external_submit.body">
</bean:message></body></html>
```

The **form** I'm submitting:

```
<form target="_parent" name="hitForm" style="visibility:hidden" id="hitForm" method="POST"
          action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit">

        <input type="hidden" id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId">
        <input type="hidden" id="hitId" name="hitId"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="workerId" name="workerId"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="caption" name="caption" value="TEST">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submitButton" value="submit" disabled="true">

    </form>
    <button ng-show="!hasAccepted()" disabled>You must first accept the HIT in order to Submit it!</button>
    <button ng-click="submitHit(inputText)" ng-show="hasAccepted()">Submit</button>
```

where the **submitHit Method** looks like this (the ids get assigned properly - i checked that):

```
$scope.submitHit = function (cap) {
    $scope.form = document.getElementById("hitForm");
    $scope.assignmentId = "";
    $scope.hitId = "";
    $scope.workerId = "";
    $scope.assignmentId = $scope.turkGetParam("assignmentId");
    $scope.hitId = $scope.turkGetParam("hitId");
    $scope.workerId = $scope.turkGetParam("workerId");
    document.getElementById("assignmentId").value = $scope.assignmentId;
    document.getElementById("hitId").value = $scope.hitId;
    document.getElementById("workerId").value = $scope.workerId;
    $scope.form.submit();
}
```

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: As always, one works nearly 2 days on this "bug" and after overcoming to ask on stackoverflow, one finds the solution:

I had to **delete the target="_parent"** in my form, I see there, everything works fine! :)

sorry for spaming you guys! ;)

Comment: Post that as the answer and accept it, so that other users learn from this. It's a good question/answer.

Comment: couldn't do that within 8 hours since I don't have enough reputation, but now it's done! ;)

Answer (score 1):

As always, one works nearly 2 days on this "bug" and after overcoming to ask on stackoverflow, one finds the solution: I had to delete the `target="_parent"` in my form and now everything works fine!